# How to use "user context access token" that I get from Twitter OAuth 1.0a in my request?

Tags: api, twitter, oauth, access-token

I have successfully (?) implement the Twitter three-legged authentication process to obtain user access token. The problem is the access token appears invalid... or I use it wrong. I already able to get the app's access token, which can access limited Twitter API. I use it by adding "Authentication: Bearer 'access token'" on the header. But when I did the same thing with the user context access token and did the same request, I always get error code 89 Invalid or expired token.

The access token I obtained has a structure of [several numerics]-[some alpha numeric chars]. Like `12345678-asd98f798asdf79asdfa9sdfs9df7a9sdf7`. This looks similar with the access token example in step 3 of https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/oauth-1-0a/obtaining-user-access-tokens.

I also notice that the example request there is like this:

```
POST statuses/update.json
oauth_consumer_key=cChZNFj6T5R0TigYB9yd1w
oauth_token=7588892-kagSNqWge8gB1WwE3plnFsJHAZVfxWD7Vb57p0b4
```

Which I presume those two additional parameters are to be added to the body instead of the header. But, how if my request is a GET request? Like request to get home timeline, which absolutely requiring user context access token?

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-home_timeline

From this API ref, the example only give the GET url, and not how to supply the user context access token. Please help. I have the feeling that the solution is very simple (like a fix on the header), but I can't see it.

This is my current request:

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=huffpost' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer 12345678-as3d12a3d1a3sd1232ads13asd123as1d23as3d32,Bearer 12345678-as3d12a3d1a3sd1232ads13asd123as1d23as3d32' \
```

This is the result:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 89,
            "message": "Invalid or expired token."
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user access token requires signing a request which includes parameters and headers.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/oauth-1-0a/authorizing-a-request

You can use a library like https://github.com/twitter/joauth to generate the signature.

For Java+OkHttp - you can use this library https://github.com/yschimke/okurl/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/baulsupp/okurl/services/twitter/joauth/Signature.kt#L33

Comment: Yea, I have just resolved it using a flutter plugin that received exactly data I have to create oauth (signature method, consumer key, consumer secret, access token, token secret), which it will help me calculate the signature hash and embed it on the header, along with the nonce. When I discovered the link you posted above, I was stunned, thinking that I have to manually follow all those steps to produce a oauth signature. Turns out there's a plugin available for that. Thanks.