# title: 'Unsupported Authentication', detail: 'Authenticating with OAuth 2.0 Application-Only is …OAuth 1.0a User Context, OAuth 2.0 User Context].'

Tags: typescript, twitter, oauth-2.0, oauth, twitter-oauth

I am using a Cloudflare worker and this is what my `index.ts` file looks like:

```
const tweet = async () => {
  console.log('tweet function ran')
  let request = await fetch("https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer <ACCESS TOKEN HERE>",
      'user-agent': "v2CreateTweetJS",
      'content-type': "application/json",
      'accept': "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({"text": "my remote Tweet"})
  })
  console.log(await request.json())
  return new Response("This response ran")
}

addEventListener('fetch', (event: FetchEvent) => {
  event.respondWith(tweet());
});
```

And when I run this code, I get this error:

```
<myusername>@<mycomputername> <myappname> % wrangler dev
  Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8787
  Detected changes...
  Ignoring stale first change
tweet function ran
{ title: 'Unsupported Authentication', detail: 'Authenticating with OAuth 2.0 Application-Only is …OAuth 1.0a User Context, OAuth 2.0 User Context].', type: 'https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/unsupported-authentication', status: 403 }
[2022-04-23 21:41:58] GET <myappname>.<mycloudflarworkername>.workers.dev/ HTTP/1.1 200 OK
^C
<myusername>@<mycomputername> <myappname> %
```

How do I fix this? I would be fine with switching to v1 APIs but I can't find any info on how to do that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message

```
Authenticating with OAuth 2.0 Application-Only
```

Indicates that the bearer token sent in the API request represents the application and not the user on whose behalf the tweet is sent. You need to obtain a token for the user who is sending the tweet.

Tweet api only accepts user context authentication as per this:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/manage-tweets/api-reference/post-tweets

However, the error seems to indicate that both OAuth 1.0 and OAuth 2.0 are supported.

The other documentation page
confirms this by saying:

**Please note that OAuth 1.0a is still required to issues requests on behalf of users.**

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0/application-only

So you should be fine with both methods.

OAuth 1.0a auth header is described here

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/authorizing-a-request

Comment: Thank you for your response! How do I get a user bearer auth token? I can't find that in my developer dashboard.

Comment: It is not a static token. In fact each token only lasts a few minutes and you will have to refresh it when it expires.  You do it via a GET request through the browser to the auth endpoint. The link I provided gives you details on how to do it. 

You may be better off with the older OAuth 1.0a approach. However, both approaches should work.

Comment: You can also use a user access token - your own token as described here. 

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/apps/overview.    Or you can use a token for any Twitter user that will allow you to post on their behalf.

Comment: The "user access token" seems like the simplest option. Again I really appreciate the help! How would I constuct the "headers" in that case? I'm only familiar with the Bearer format. Also would my "user access token" be the "access token" or "access secret" in my Twitter Developer dashboard?

Comment: I agree. In OAuth 1.0a they use a slightly different format. You will see it if you look at the docs. I did see it as I was researching my answer.

Comment: Please see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59557902/how-to-use-user-context-access-token-that-i-get-from-twitter-oauth-1-0a-in-my